# How do I delete a voice memo from my itunes?

Tags: voice-memo

I did not check off the option to sync my voice memos, yet I still see my voice memos on my itunes. It does not give me an option to delete it from itunes. however I have already deleted it from my phone. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: What worked for me was to 1) manually search for all *.m4a voice memos  files using spotlight on finder 2) moving them to trash 3) emptying the trash 4) in iTunes -> iPhone -> Summary clicking "Manually manage music and videos" and "Apply"

Answer (score 1):

Highlight all of the memos, and then press either the delete button on your keyboard or (as mentioned below) Command+Delete.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Command + Delete?

Comment: Make sure you're not in a playlist when doing this.

Comment: @EmerickRogul so where should you be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I highlighted the voice memos and then hit the space bar. You have to hit where it says to put it in the trash. That's all I did and it worked.

Comment: Can you update your answer for the latest iTunes